# I m trying to plot 5 histogram in 2 rows and 3 columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I m trying to plot 5 histogram in 2 rows and 3 columns using python. The columns contain categorical variable. But the command give an error "dataframe object not callable". This is the code.

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8)) 
plt.subplot(2,3,1) 
df4.get_group('Basic Level').plot(kind = 'hist') 
plt.subplot(2,3,2) 
df4.get_group("Doctorate").plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,3) 
df4.get_group("Graduate").plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,4) 
df4.get_group("Illiterate").plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,5) 
df4.get_group("Post Graduate").plot(kind = 'hist' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first extract the group data and then plot it as a histogram. I assume you `groupby` first but just to mention it:

```
df4 = df.groupby("[insert Name of your column]")
```

after that you can use the following to produce your diagram

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8)) 
plt.subplot(2,3,1) 
df4_group1 = df4.get_group('Basic Level')
df4_group1.plot(kind = 'hist') 
plt.subplot(2,3,2) 
df4_group2 = df4.get_group("Doctorate")
df4_group2.plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,3) 
df4_group3 = df4.get_group("Graduate")
df4_group3.plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,4) 
df4_group4 = df4.get_group("Illiterate")
df4_group4.plot(kind = 'hist' ) 
plt.subplot(2,3,5) 
df4_group5 = df4.get_group("Post Graduate")
df4_group5.plot(kind = 'hist' )
```